# Star Wars: Rebellion - How many mission cards can have leaders assigned to?

Tags: star-wars-rebellion

The rule book says regarding the ASSIGNMENT PHASE:

"During this phase, players assign their leaders to missions."

Is there a maximum number of missions that can be played during this phase? If I have 5 leaders, por example, can I assign them to 5 different missions on a single turn?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. The only limits for the number of mission you can run in a single turn are your number of available leaders, and the number of cards in your hand.